# How to push tab bar to other view controller

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, ios5

I have a tab bar fully worked but how can i push an tab bar item to another view controller?

Code:

```
- (void)tabBar:(UITabBar *)tabBar didSelectItem:(UITabBarItem *)item {

    switch (item.tag) {
        case 0:
            break;
        case 1:


            break;
        case 2:

            break;
        case 3:
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: What? What do you want to do? Do you want to navigate between tabs? That will happen automatically when the user selects a tab. Are you using a UITabBarController?

Comment: I'm using an UITabBar when a user taps on the first tap i want to redirect the user to the view controller '1'

Comment: Ok, so why aren't you using a UITabBarController? It might be exactly what you are looking for, no need to reinvent the wheel: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITabBarController_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a UITabBarController. Create it, create your desired custom view controller, and then do:

```
tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:customController1,
customController2, customController3, nil];
```

Then grab access to your window and put the UITabBarController into the window like so:

```
[window addSubview:tabBarController.view];
```